# NuGet package icon refresh

Tags: nuget

In my NuGet package's specification, there's a URL for the icon that points an image in the project's GitHub hosted repo.

Unfortunately, I pushed the NuGet package before I pushed the commit that introduced the icon image. NuGet.org seems to have checked the URL when I pushed the package, observed the 404, and not attempted again (it's been two and a half days).

Is it possible to force a refresh? I don't anticipate needing to update the package for a while, and I'd rather not push a new version just to trigger the icon refresh.

Comment: can you point me to your nuget package....or reach out to me at karann[at]microsoft[dot]com

Comment: @karann, thanks for following up, but actually I made a mistake. The package is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FamFamFam.Flags.Wpf/). I used an incorrect URL. The one I specified returns an [HTML page](https://github.com/drewnoakes/famfamfam-flags-wpf/blob/master/logo.png) showing the image, not the [raw image](https://github.com/drewnoakes/famfamfam-flags-wpf/raw/master/logo.png) directly. I suppose the only way to correct this now is to publish a new version of the package.

Comment: you don't have to upload a new package. You can login to nuget.org, navigate to your package page, and click on the edit link - and you'd be able to edit the icon url.

Comment: @karann, thanks very much. I wasn't aware that was possible.